# How to make interface for this small service in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am building some kind of REST Api Client in C#.
I wrote some code for getting model from another project and returning it in console (some kind of GET method).

But I want to build interface for that. How can I do it?

**companyService.cs**

```
    public class CompanyService
{
    private HttpClient httpClient;
    private CompanyClient companyClient;

    public CompanyService(string url, string token)
    {
        httpClient = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(url),
        };

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers
            .AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

        companyClient = new CompanyClient(url, httpClient);
    }

    public async Task<ICollection<CompanyModel>> GetCompanies()
    {
        return await companyClient.CompanyAsync();
    }

}
```

**Task to run this**

```
        public static async Task Test()
    {
        const string ApiAddress = "https://localhost:44309";

        try
        {
            var authService = new AuthService(ApiAddress);
            var token = await authService.GetToken("test", "test123");

            var companyService = new CompanyService(ApiAddress, token);
            var companies = await companyService.GetCompanies();

            foreach (var company in companies)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(company.Name);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {exception.Message}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "build an interface"? It's not clear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Have a look into "strongly typed HttpClient" and perhaps Refit. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests and https://github.com/reactiveui/refit

Comment: Pls allow me to post my guess below, if I misunderstood you, could you pls add more details on your requirement?

Comment: Any progress or further issue? If you feel my post is helpful to you, could you pls accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I also can't get what you mean of 'build an interface', and if you wanna create an interface to make your `CompanyService` class to implement it so that you can use dependency injection, I think you can take these steps.

Firstly, adding an interface class named `ICompanyService` in the same folder as `CompanyService`, and the content like this:

```
public interface ICompanyService
{
    public Task<ICollection<CompanyModel>> GetCompanies();
}
```

Then you need to change `public class CompanyService` to `public class CompanyService : ICompanyService`.

At last, injecting services into Startup.cs, in `ConfigureServices` method, adding line-code like `services.AddScoped<ICompanyService, CompanyService>();`, you can also refer to [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes) to learn about service lifetimes.

And from now on, you can make your CompanyService be injected into other services rather than new it in method.